# how to persist or re-use impersonate token in windows?

Tags: java, windows, jna, advapi32

I'm using

Dependency: implementation group: "net.java.dev.jna", name: "jna"

Code:

```
PointerByReference phToken = new PointerByReference();
advapi32.LogonUserW(new WString(username), new WString(domain), new WString(password), 3, 0, phToken);
```

Now i need to re-use the phToken, so that i don't need to login again. I was thinking to extract out the token, and persist that in db, and then re-use as per need. but, i was not able to extract out the token, hence facing difficulty in that. Please guide me, how to re-use the token. Also, this token i can't persist/save in windows, it will be another service, so will have to send this as json to another service.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're using JNA to interact with the Windows API isn't really relevant here.  Ultimately you're just using the [LogonUserW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw) function.

The return value from that, `phToken`, is a pointer to a `HANDLE`.  This handle is just a 64-bit value which represents the actual user logon token, but you're only working with a process-local copy of it.  You also don't directly interact with the token, but only use a set of API methods using that handle (or a pointer to it) to manipulate it.

The API specifies that you should close the handle when you're done with it, otherwise you'd leak resources.  And once it's closed, that 64-bit value has no meaning.  If you request another handle, it very well may be a different 64-bit number.

Once the current process ends, the handle would be automatically closed anyway.

So ultimately, if you want to store that 64-bit number in a database somewhere, you're welcome to do so.  It would only be usable by the same process that created it, as long as that handle wasn't closed, in which case there is likely no need for external storage.

If you do have such a use case, you would simply recreate the `HANDLE` (the token representation) which you could use to instantiate a `HANDLEByReference` if needed.  You can create the handle from a `Pointer` which you can set the peer value to the 64-bit number you retrieved earlier.